# google map displaying default data

Tags: php, google-maps

iam using google map in my php script to display the address of a company.
But the map is only displaying the default city location of the address, not going deep.

For example, if i specify the address as: 
Angadalavari Street, Behind Bodima Hotel, Kothapet, Vijayawada

But the map is showing only the location Governorpeta, Vijayawada

What could be the reason?

Comment: how are you getting / giving the location to google maps?

Comment: i have locations of companies in database and providing them to php script in realtime, which takes care of displaying map using an api.

Comment: 13 questions and you only recognized 2 answers! very ungrateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mentioning the ADDRESS is not enough ..it is better specify the LONGITUDE and LATITUDE for exact location ....

Here is the Sample Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function initialize(){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.88411739850852, 84.58428740501404);//Location for BARUVA,ANDHRAPRADESH,INDIA
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), myOptions);
        }
    </script>
```